# Numpy can_cast on array returns False even when casting is safe

Tags: python, numpy

Python 3 test:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.can_cast(np.arange(100), np.uint32, casting='safe'))
```

This prints `False` although all values between 0 and 100 can be safely represented by unsigned 32bit integers.

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.can_cast.html) of `numpy.can_cast`:

> Returns True if cast between data types can occur according to the
>   casting rule. If from is a scalar or array scalar, also returns True
>   if the scalar value can be cast without overflow or truncation to an
>   integer.

Why does it return `False` in this case?

If I should not use `can_cast`, what should I use?

The numpy version is 1.12.1 (as returned by `np.version.version`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.arange(100)` is an array (and not a scalar array), so only the data types are checked, not the individual values.

For example,

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.arange(100)

In [3]: np.can_cast(x, np.uint32, casting='safe')
Out[3]: False

In [4]: all(np.can_cast(v, np.uint32, casting='safe') for v in x)
Out[4]: True
```